# Mongoose not returning anything hanging until connection timesout

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

My login script was working fine but only for one record, all the rest hang and do not return not quite sure why?

It reutrns the email and password from my console.log but not the console.log of the user. Also can confirm that the users email does exist in the db

Below is my basic setup.

User model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var passwordString = require("../helper/generateStrongRandomString");

var schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        validator: function (v) {
          return /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/.test(
            v
          );
        },
        message: (props) => `${props.value} is not a valid email address`,
      },
    },
    organisation: {
      ref: "organisation",
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
    },
    client: {
      ref: "client",
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: false,
    },
    forename: {
      type: String,
    },
    surname: {
      type: String,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    created: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
    },
    updated: {
      type: Date,
      default: null,
    },
    passwordResetString: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

schema.pre("save", function (next) {
  var user = this;

  if (!user.isNew) {
    user.updated = Date.now();
  }

  if (user.isNew && !user.password) {
    user.passwordResetString = passwordString();
  }

  if (!user.isModified("password")) {
    return next();
  }

  bcrypt
    .hash(user.password, 12)
    .then((hash) => {
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

schema.pre("save", function (next) {
  var user = this;
  user.updated = Date.now();
  next();
});

function autopopulate(next) {
  this.populate("organisation");
  this.populate("client");
  next();
}

schema.pre("find", autopopulate);
schema.pre("findOne", autopopulate);

var User = new mongoose.model("user", schema);

module.exports = User;
```

Login route

```
const router = require("express").Router();

const passport = require("passport");

const catchErrors = require("../middlewares/catchErrors");

router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local"),
  catchErrors(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    // console.log(req);
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

Passport js local authentication

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    },
    async function (email, password, cb) {
      console.log(email, password);
      return User.findOne({ email })
        .then((user) => {
          console.log(user);
          if (!user || !bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            console.log(26);
            return cb(null, false, {
              message: "incorrect email or password",
            });
          }
          return cb(null, user, {
            message: "Logged in successfully",
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles across this, I figured it out. My problem was with my autopopulate and the organisation model not shown above see code below.

```
function autopopulate(next) {
  this.populate("organisation");
  this.populate("client");
  next();
}
```

This loads and populates the organisation as part of the user data however my organisation was doing the exact same thing when it was loaded on the user and causing an infinite loop.

Lots of commenting out of code and checking to confirm.

Look out for infinite loops.